# PHP/MYSQL: Best practice for Like System with Multiple Item-Types

Tags: mysql, facebook-like

I am implementing a like system on my website for actions that appear in a feed. The feed consists of records, if you will, from various different tables.  For example, when someone adds a contact, this appears in the feed.  Or when someone completes an action this appears in the feed.  The contacts and the actions come from different tables. I would like people to record their likes and dislikes.

The conventional wisdom seems to be that for a like system you create a separate likes table where every row corresponds to a like or unlike of something by a user.  It would look like the following:

```
id|user_id|item_id|like|unlike
 1|    222|    333|   1|     0
 2|    230|    333|   1|     0
 2|    942|    333|   0|     1
```

You are then supposed to count up the likes and unlikes to get the number.  In the above example, item_id 333 would show 1 net like, two likes from users 220 and 230 minus one dislike from user 942.

For multiple tables would I just replace item_id with more than one column as in:

```
id|user_id|contact_id|action_id|like|unlike
```

or perhaps have a separate column for type of item as in:

```
id|user_id|type_of_item_item_id|like|unlike
```

Would appreciate any suggestions on the best way to do this.